# Help for solving a PDE: $\partial_1 u(x) + u(x)b(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Let $b : \mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a $C^1(\mathbb R^N)$ known function. We are looking for a solution $ u : \mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ of the following PDE :

$$\partial_1 u(x) + u(x)b(x) = 0 \ \ \ (1)$$
where $\partial_1 $ is the partial derivative of u with respect to $x_1$.

And so, more generally, let now $ c : \mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ be a $C^1(\mathbb R^N)$ vector field, we want to solve :
$$\nabla u(x) + u(x)c(x) = 0 \ \ \ (2) $$

But I guess (2) follows from (1).

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: $(1)$ is just a first order ODE, and $(2)$ is a set of first order ODEs, so why can't you use an integrating factor? The solution to the first is just $$u = u_{0}(x_{2},\dots,x_{n}) \exp \left(- \int b(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}) \ dx_{1} \right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the components $(x_2,x_3,\dots x_n)$ can be considered parameters, since your equation does not involve differentiation with respect to them. You can call $f(t)=u(t,x_2,x_3,\dots x_n)$ and $g(t)=b(t,x_2,x_3,\dots x_n)$. Your equation reads
$$
f'(t)+f(t)g(t)=0
$$
which is linear and has solution
$$
f(t)=Ce^{-\int_0^tg(s)ds}
$$
Therefore, your original equation has solution
$$
u(x_1,x_2,\dots x_n)=Ce^{-\int_0^{x_1}b(s,x_2,x_3,\dots x_n)ds}
$$